# command line to flush php session on linux box

Tags: php, linux

I have a LAMP stack on AWS centOS linux. After updating my site i would like to force all users to re login by clearing all sessions.
What is the best way to do this?
Is there a way to flush out all sessions currently in PHP?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This very much depends on where your application stores the session. If you have not manually overridden the session handler in your project it will default to whatever the path is in your php.ini file. To locate your php.ini file:

```
$ find / -name php.ini
```

On CentOS it's usually found in /etc/php.ini.

Check php.ini for the session save path (defaults to /tmp I think on PHP-FPM CentOS installs):

```
session.save_path = "/var/lib/php/session"
```

Delete the contents of the specified folder:

```
$ rm -Rf /var/lib/php/session/*
```

Now all of the current user sessions should be cleared. If you store sessions in the DB or memory, you will need to clear the sessions manually via whatever software you use for session management.

Comment: im getting a `cannot read directory â/var/lib/php/sessionâ: Permission denied` so i ran sudo `sudo rm -Rf /var/lib/php/session/*`  but the session is not cleared

Comment: changed ownership to apache: `sudo chown -R apache:apache /var/lib/php/session` but still the same  result

Comment: what i did was change the ownership to local user, then go to that folder using `sftp` program and manually delete the content of this directory

Comment: OH NO,  now php cannot write into session! `Warning: Unknown: Failed to write session data (files). Please verify that the current setting of session.save_path is correct (/var/lib/php/session) in Unknown on line 0`

Comment: changing the ownership to `apache` from `root` solved the issue

Comment: Works perfect, but using root user

Answer (score 1):

There is no "flush session" command. You can achieve the same effect by removing the sessions from your session store. By default php stores session in files so by deleting those files you could force all clients to login again.

Session store path is configured by using this configuration directive:
http://us.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.save-path

Edit: 
I have found the default session path on centos. It's /var/lib/php/session
so the command would be

```
rm -rf /var/lib/php/session/*
```

I would reccomend you to backup before doing this the first time because I have not tested it.